# How to select documents with one field greater than other in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have mongodb documents like this

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 52135a6baabacb9f948b4567
)
[change] => 7
[from] => 8
[to] => 1
```

How to select documents with field "from" greater than "to" in MongoDB? I tried something like this but it doesn't work at all.

```
$collection->find( array('from' => array('$gt' => 'to') ) );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend against using `$where`.  It will be slow at scale.

For this use case, you will want to move your logic from your query to your document schema.  Add a new attribute to your document called "from_to_diff" and set it to "from" - "to" at document write time.

Then, run the following query:

`$collection->find(array('from' => array('$gt' => 0)))`

Then, create an index on {from_to_diff: 1}.  You will have good cardinality on your index, and not run the massive table scans you will have with `$where`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this ;)

```
$collection->find( array('$where' => 'this.from > this.to'  ) );
```